# How do I get backbone to bind the submit event to a form?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm using the following code to create the view:

```
LoginForm = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName :"form"
    ,id : "login-form"
    ,className :"navbar-form"
    ,initialize: function () {
            this.model = new StackMob.User();
            this.render();
    }
    ,render: function () {
            $(this.el).html(this.template());
            return this;
    }
    ,events : {
            "change" : "change"
            ,"submit #login-form" : "login"
    }
    ,login : function( event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var self = this;
            this.model.login(true, {
                    success: function( model) {
                            app.alertSuccess( "User logged in");
                            self.render();
                    }
                    ,error: function( model, response) {
                            app.alertError("Could not login  user: " + response.error_description);
                    }
            });
            event.currentTarget.checkValidity();
            return false;
    }
// rest of code
```

And the template:

```
<input name="username" class="span2" type="email" placeholder="Email" required >
<input name="password" class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password" required >
<button id="login-button" type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
```

When I bind on the button, the login function gets called.  Binding on the form submit event, the login function does not get called.  I can also get the form to bind if the id & form tag are part of the template, which is not what I want to do here.

How do I bind on the form submit in this case?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
"submit #login-form" : "login"
```

I think Backbone will search for this id among the descendants only. So it will never match your own view element. Why don't you just use:

```
"submit": "login"
```

As you did for change.
Gonna check Backbone's code just to be sure.

**Edit:**
If you put a selector, Backbone will call

```
this.$el.on(event, selector, method);
```

instead of

```
this.$el.on(event, method);
```

And the on method of jQuery will instead apply the selector to the **descendants** of the element only, excluding the element itself.

Comment: The relevant documentation is hidden inside the [`delegateEvents`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents) documentation: "Omitting the `selector` causes the event to be bound to the view's root element `(this.el)`."

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't exclude what he was doing. Well, I guess it's still enough information.

Comment: I would hope everyone would [read my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29465198/124486), because this is waaaackk advice.

Answer (score 3):

You're using Backbone wrong. So what you're going to want to do,

```
template: my_template_string,
render: function () {
    this.el.innerHTML = this.template();
},
events: {
    "submit #login-form": function (event) {}
}
```

Where `this.template` is set to

```
<form id="login-form" class="navbar-form">
    <input name="username" class="span2" type="email" placeholder="Email" required >
    <input name="password" class="span2" type="password" placeholder="Password" required >
    <button id="login-button" type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

And doesn't that *only* make sense? Why would you want the id and classname to be separated from the input elements? BTW, you can still do the naked catchall on `submit`, but only in my method will,

- the `<form>` class, and `<form>` attribute be tied to the form's template, and not just the backbone view,
- will you be explicitly capturing the right submit,
- can you ever support multiple submit events (in the event one template has two forms).

Comment: You are talking about "zombie views" issue? id/tagName ain't related to the issue at all.

Comment: @suish yea, I agree my reason for not using tagname, and className, id is slightly different. I was serving them on the page and not letting Backbone create them. I've removed my rants about that and left the other more applicable parts of the answer. I still advice never using that functionality. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe When you bind on the form submit event, it is only submit the form will fire the 'submit' event. you could add below code and try it again.

```
$('#id').submit(function(ev) {

});
```