# Simple button click in backbone

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying out different functionalities using backbone and i came accross a strange one. I am trying to submit a form through backbone. I had done this previously and i cannot find whats wrong with what i am doing.

The code is as follows :

**HTML Part**

```
   <div clas="loginpage"></div>
   <form class="login-user-form">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"><br><br>
     <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
   </form>
```

**jQuery Part**

```
var UserLogin = Backbone.View.extend({
   el:'.loginpage',
   initialize:function(){
   console.log("Login View Initialized");
 },
 events:{
   'submit .btn' : 'loginuser'
 },
 loginuser:function(){
   console.log("Login Clicked.");
   return false;
 }
});
var userlogin = new UserLogin();
```

I get Login View Initialized message in console. But i cannot get the loginuser function to work. The page submits through its default submit functionality.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `loginpage` doesn't contain the form. Fix:

```
<div class="loginpage">
  <form class="login-user-form">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"><br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Create</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

2)

```
events : {
 'submit' : 'loginuser'
},

loginuser : function(){
  console.log("Login Clicked.");
  return false; // Stops default html form submission
}
```

Comment: If i remove the return false, the basic html form submission take place. This i wanted to handle through jquery itself and hence added the return false.:)..

Answer (score 0):

Got it working :

```
events:{   
    'submit' : 'loginuser'
}
```

Got this from the following thread : [How do I get backbone to bind the submit event to a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685718/cant-get-backbone-to-bind-the-submit-event-of-a-form?rq=1)

Cheers ..:)